# How to get the last build artifact out of the TFS build drop?

Tags: tfsbuild

Our existing batch build script contains an URL to get the latest product-build (of another build definition) from.

How can one access the lattest build drop folder of TFS Team Build?

I'm looking for something to access the latest \buildserver\builddrop\Project-2010MMDD.N\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the API, you can get the drop location from the build.  The code below gets the most recent build for a given project, and returns the dropfolder.

```cs
public string DropFolder(TeamFoundationServer tfs, string teamProject, string buildName)
{
    IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

    IBuildDetailSpec buildDetailSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(teamProject, buildName);

    buildDetailSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
    buildDetailSpec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
    buildDetailSpec.Status = BuildStatus.Failed | BuildStatus.PartiallySucceeded | BuildStatus.Stopped | BuildStatus.Succeeded;

    IBuildQueryResult results = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDetailSpec);

    if (results.Failures.Length != 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("this needs to go away and be handled more nicely");
    }

    if (results.Builds.Length == 1)
    {
        results.Builds[0].DropLocation;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if writing a small utility app to do this isn't in the cards, the same API is exposed to PowerShell.